# Linq join returning duplicate results

Tags: c#, linq, join, duplicates

I'm using LINQ to try to get all the clothes of my characters.

My query looks like this:

```
var characterList = from characters in ContextFactory.Instance.Characters
                    where characters.UserId == user.Id

                    join traits in ContextFactory.Instance.CharacterTraits
                    on characters.Id equals traits.CharacterId
                    join clothes in ContextFactory.Instance.CharacterClothes
                    on characters.Id equals clothes.CharacterId
                    select new { 
                        characters.Id, 
                        characters.Name, 
                        characters.Gender, 
                        characters.Level, 
                        characters.Money, 
                        characters.Bank, 
                        characters.LastLogin, 
                        characters.PlayedTime, 
                        traits, 
                        clothes };
```

Then I'm serializing it to use as JSON in javascript.

This code is returning an user for each clothe I have, I wanted it to group all the clothes in an array. How could I do that?

Current result:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do so you need to use `GroupJoin`: *Notice the addition of the `into` at the end of the join*

```
var characterList = from characters in ContextFactory.Instance.Characters
                    where characters.UserId == user.Id
                    join t in ContextFactory.Instance.CharacterTraits
                    on characters.Id equals t.CharacterId into traits 
                    join c in ContextFactory.Instance.CharacterClothes into clothes
                    on characters.Id equals c.CharacterId
                    select new { /* As before */ }
```

Read more on MSDN: [Perform Grouped Joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins)

Notice that if you are using EF there is no need for writing the joins. Properly defining the Navigation Properties and using `Include` will give you what you are looking for in much less work.

---

Last, notice that even when having the `Where` condition this will return an `IEnumerable<>` of results. If you want only one record with all this information then add at the end, wrapping it all, a `FirstOrDefault` or better still remove the `where` clause in the query and do:

```
var character = (from characters in ContextFactory.Instance.Characters
                 join t in ContextFactory.Instance.CharacterTraits
                 on characters.Id equals t.CharacterId into traits 
                 join c in ContextFactory.Instance.CharacterClothes into clothes
                 on characters.Id equals c.CharacterId
                 select new { /* As before */ }).FirstOrDefault( x=> x.id = user.Id);
```

Comment: @Wuzi - Did this solution help you solve your problem?

Comment: I tried that and for some reason i was getting an error (invalid expression term 'into'), then i saw you mentioned Navigation Properties, I am fairly new to EF so I started looking into it. I finally managed to do what i needed with Navigation Properties! Thank you. Basically all I did was adding this to my Character model: ```public virtual ICollection<CharacterClothes> Clothes { get; set; }```

Answer (score 0):

See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            User user = new User();

            var characterList = (from characters in ContextFactory.Instance.Characters
            where characters.UserId == user.Id
            join traits in ContextFactory.Instance.CharacterTraits
            on characters.Id equals traits.CharacterId
            join clothes in ContextFactory.Instance.CharacterClothes
            on characters.Id equals clothes.CharacterId
            select new { characters = characters, traits = traits, clothes = clothes })
            .GroupBy(x => x.characters.Id)
            .Select(x => new { 
                id = x.FirstOrDefault().characters.Id, 
                name = x.FirstOrDefault().characters.Name, 
                gender = x.FirstOrDefault().characters.Gender, 
                level = x.FirstOrDefault().characters.Level, 
                money = x.FirstOrDefault().characters.Money, 
                bank = x.FirstOrDefault().characters.Bank, 
                lastLogin = x.FirstOrDefault().characters.LastLogin, 
                playedTime = x.FirstOrDefault().characters.PlayedTime, 
                traits = x.FirstOrDefault().traits, 
                clothes = x.Select(y => y.clothes.clothes).ToArray()
            }).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }

    public class ContextFactory
    {
        public static Instance Instance = null;
    }
    public class Instance
    {
        public List<Characters> Characters;
        public List<CharactersTraits> CharacterTraits;
        public List<CharactersClothes> CharacterClothes;
    }
    public class Characters
    {
        public int Id;
        public int UserId;
        public string Name;
        public string Gender;
        public string Level;
        public string Money;
        public string Bank;
        public string LastLogin;
        public string PlayedTime;
    }
    public class CharactersTraits
    {
        public int CharacterId;
    }
    public class CharactersClothes
    {
        public int CharacterId;
        public string clothes;
    }
    public class User
    {
        public int Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Thank you, i managed to do that using Navigation Properties on EF.